# Ektron workarea meta-data saving error: "There was no endpoint listening at..."

Tags: ektron

When updating meta-data on a page or in the Ektron workarea Settings, then this error is returned.

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://example.com:8732/Ektron.ASM.EktronServices/CmsHelperService2.svc
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details.

It mentions the Ektron Windows Service.

The meta-data is not propogating to the folder metadata options. Only to new folders that are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that address configured in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ektron\EktronWindowsService40\Ektron.ASM.EktronServices40.exe.config

The config points to a logs/ folder, the logs folder contains the following error which led me to this article: https://portal.ektron.com/KB/1088/

Which says:

> "Check 'Windows features' or 'Role Services' for IIS6 Metabase
>   compatibility, add if missing:"
>   [image]